# How do I fix my font rendering on Void Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, configuration, customization

I've recently installed base Void Linux distribution along with the i3 window manager, and the problem is that my fonts are really pixelated / not smooth across all the distro, where text is present (Firefox, file manager, the terminal etc.)

I found this article on the official docs of Void: https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/graphical-session/fonts.html

But the command mentioned there did not help me, my fonts are still not rendered smoothly.

Here's how my fonts look: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuB5Q.png)

I'm aware that I need to edit my font config file, but I don't know what to do exactly, and I'm afraid to do any changes on myself as to not to break my distro completely

Here's the output of fc-conflist command:

```
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf: Set hintslight to hintstyle
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf: Bitmap scaling
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf: Use lcddefault as default for LCD filter
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-serif.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf: Disable hinting for Bitstream Vera fonts when the size is less than 8ppem
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf: Set substitutions for similar/metric-compatible families
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf: Set substitutions for non-Latin fonts
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/42-luxi-mono.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf: Set substitutions for emoji/math fonts
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf: Set substitutions for Latin fonts
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/48-spacing.conf: Add mono to the family when spacing is 100
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf: Add sans-serif to the family when no generic name
+ /home/pavel/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/19-DefaultProperties.conf: No description
+ /home/pavel/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/19-DisplayProperties.conf: No description
+ /home/pavel/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/39-Aliases.conf: No description
+ /home/pavel/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/78-Reject.conf: No description
+ /home/pavel/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf: Load per-user customization files
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf: Load local customization file
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-sans-mono.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-sans.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-serif.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf: Set preferable fonts for emoji/math fonts
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf: Set preferable fonts for Latin
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf: Set preferable fonts for non-Latin
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf: No description
+ /etc/fonts/fonts.conf: Default configuration file
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf: Re-define fonts dirs sample
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/09-autohint-if-no-hinting.conf: Enable autohinter if font doesn't have any hinting
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-autohint.conf: Enable autohinter
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf: Set hintfull to hintstyle
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-hinting-medium.conf: Set hintmedium to hintstyle
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-hinting-none.conf: Set hintnone to hintstyle
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-no-sub-pixel.conf: Disable sub-pixel rendering
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-bgr.conf: Enable sub-pixel rendering with the BGR stripes layout
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf: Enable sub-pixel rendering with the RGB stripes layout
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-vbgr.conf: Enable sub-pixel rendering with the vertical BGR stripes layout
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-vrgb.conf: Enable sub-pixel rendering with the vertical RGB stripes layout
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-unhinted.conf: Disable hinting
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-legacy.conf: Use lcdlegacy as default for LCD filter
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-light.conf: Use lcdlight as default for LCD filter
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/25-unhint-nonlatin.conf: Disable hinting for CJK fonts
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/35-lang-normalize.conf: No description
- /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/65-khmer.conf: No description
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing some fonts like iosevka and make it the default in for example firefox and see what happens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).